# Datatable id default button

Tags: datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and I have built my code in this way:

```
  table = $('#examples').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        type: "POST",
        url: "./../../" + "/back-end/switch-ajax-listening/switch-ajax-listening.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:
            {
                actionId: "page1GetAll"
            }

    },
    responsive: true,
    

    "columns": [
        { "data": "idSelectPacketName"},
        { "data": "idSelectCompany" },
        { "data": "idSelectDesigner1" },
        { "data": "idSelectDesigner2" },
        { "data": "idSelectDesigner3" },
        { "data": "idSelectDesigner4" },
        { "data": "idSelectDesigner5" },
        { "data": "idSelectManufacturer" },
        { "data": "idSelectorProductSector" },
        { "data": "idSelectorProductionYear" },
        { "data": "idSelectorNation" },
        { "data": "idSelectorTypology" },
        { "data": "idHeightInput"},
        { "data": "idLengthInput" },
        { "data": "idVolumeInput" },
        { "data": "idWeightInput" },
        { "data": "nameOutMouseOrImage1" },
        { "data": "nameOverMouseOrImage2" },
        {"data":null,"defaultContent":"<button>View</button>"}

    ],
});

var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {

    "buttons": [

        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ],
            container : '#colvis',
            columns: '0,1,2,3,4,5'
        },
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ],
}).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));

$('div.dataTables_filter').appendTo('#buttons');

$("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
```

It works very well but I need to move some element using the id. Indeed at the end of my code I have moved some elements in new div using their id, but I'm not able to find all the id. More in details I don't find this id:[image]

I have indicated with orange and blue color.

Have you some ideas what is their id name?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for Datatable dom positioning

You can position each component in any order something like this

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
});
```

where variables are

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The Table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
```

you can change order of `irtflp` in order you want

More detail [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)